# sqlite scientific notation during select

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I have several columns of real values I'd like to show in scientific notations.  Seems like a fairly obvious question, but how does one show scientific notations during SELECT command in SQLite. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT` commands produce integers, floats, strings, blobs, etc. They produce the data structures stored in the database. You get them with the equivalent C types.

What you're asking for has nothing to do with SQLite, because SQLite will return `float`s for floating-point numerical values. What you need is a way to turn a C `float` type into a *string* representation that is in scientific notation. This is done outside of SQLite.

What you want, using standard C library functions, is `snprintf` (note: pre-C99 does not offer `snprintf`. C++ doesn't offer `snprintf`, though many C++ compilers will give it to you. Visual Studio has `_snprintf`. You can either use those non-standard version or `std::stringstream` using [IOS manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). In any case  It offers **never ever use `sprintf`!**):

```
char outputString[40];
snprintf(outputString, 40, "%e", yourFloatTakenFromSQLite);
```

You can look up the `printf` formatting to see how to control how many decimal places you get.

Comment: i just assumed such formatting exist at the select level.   Would be nice if such feature exists so I don't have to manage that myself.  But I can see why string manipulation would be disallowed at the select level. thanks.